# How to shift the drag and drop feedback to the left?

Tags: flutter, drag-and-drop

I am building a chess board component, in which we should move the pieces by a simple Drag And Drop. In order to ease the drag and drop, I also try to draw a feedback which is a "cross of cells" centered around the pointer.

So, I am trying this way :

1. I draw a container that starts at the pointer location
2. Inside that container, I draw the entire cross, also drawing the dragged piece at the center of this container
3. So, I need a way to shift that feedback half to the left and to the top. That is, I need the feedback to be positionned to left and to the top of the pointer location.

Is that possible ?

I've tried playing with `feedback` and `dragAnchor` properties of Draggable, but I did not achieve.